# How to change \slice{} color on quantikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles, quantikz

Within [quantikz](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1809.03842.pdf) package there's this possibility to put a single slice to separate two columns, through the command `\slice{}`.

By default it is colored in red and no standard command allows to change that.

Can someone explain me how can I overcome this problem, even by changing the package itself if necessary. Which I believe is [this one](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/quantikz).

Below a simple example; a circuit of four steps but with a slice only in the middle.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{quantikz}[slice style=blue]
        \gate{X} & \gate{I} & \slice{1}\gate{I} & \gate{Y}
    \end{quantikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome to the TeX.SE. community. Please can you put a minimal working example of your idea? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put it in the optional argument of `\slice`:

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{quantikz}[]
        \gate{X} & \gate{I} & \slice[style=blue]{1}\gate{I} & \gate{Y}
    \end{quantikz}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can change it using `slice/.append style`, as below.

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{quantikz}
\tikzset{slice/.append style={draw=blue}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{quantikz}
        \gate{X} & \gate{I} & \slice{1}\gate{I} & \gate{Y}
    \end{quantikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]